# Regex code how to filter all names that contain only numbers and end with .jpg and/or _number.jpg?

Tags: regex, sql-server-2008, ssis, expression

How to filter all names that consist of numbers and end with .jpg and/or _number.jpg?

Background info:
In SSIS 2008 I have a foreach loop that will store the filename into a variable for all jpg files. The enumorator configuration for Files is currently: `*.jpg` 
This will handle all jpg files.

**What is the code so it will only handle names likes?**:

```
3417761506233.jpg
3417761506233_1.jpg
5414233177487.jpg
5414233177487_1.jpg
5414233177487_14.jpg
```

but not names like:

```
abc.jpg
abc123.jpg
def.png
456.png
```

The numbers represent EAN codes by the way. 
I thought about this code:

`\d|_|.jpg`

but SSIS returns an error stating there are no files that meet the criteria eventhough the files(names) are in the folder.

[image]

Comment: Did you try to choose "Name and extension" radio button?

Comment: No I didn't, but if I am correct the Retrieve file name is for the thing you like to retrieve from the file and store into the variable, in this case the name only. The folder is which directory to look in and the Files is which files to look for. I could try of course, but it would surprise me if that would be the solution. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't know this apps, It was just an idea!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Script Task within the loop to do the regex filtering:
http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/04/regex-filter-for-foreach-loop.html
[image]

Or you could use a (free) Third Party Enumerator:
http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2012/04/custom-ssis-component-foreach-file.html
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Joost, that's exactly what I was looking for. I will try the 3rd party tool. See they have more usefull enumerators.

Answer (score 1):

For that, you can use the following regex:

`^\d+(_\d+)?.jpg$`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/qC7oV3

Comment: Thank you @sshashank124, it is the answer to my question, but unfortunately SSIS'08 doesn't handle the regex the way I hoped. It still returns an error stating: Warning: The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(\d+(?:_\d+)?\.jpg$)
```

**DEMO -->** http://regex101.com/r/dM9rJ7

**Matches:**

```
3417761506233.jpg
3417761506233_1.jpg
5414233177487.jpg
5414233177487_1.jpg
5414233177487_14.jpg
```

**Excludes:**

```
abc.jpg
abc123.jpg
def.png
456.png
```